# Tweaking phonegap camera plugin to show 'camera view' within the app

Tags: android-intent, cordova, plugins, camera

Is it possible to open a camera view within an app (built using phonegap)?
I did some research and discovered that phonegap camera plugin uses intents, while, what I need to be done requires the use of camera API provided by android device. I understand that I need to perform massive tweaks in the plugin, or create my own. All I want to know is if its possible

I will post further queries if doing this is possible

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Basically anything you can do in native code (such as access native camera API), you can expose to your Phonegap app via a custom plugin.  Seems straightforward though so I am guessing that is not what you are asking.  Please clarify.

Comment: thanks SoldierOfFortran.
I need to let the user of my app select camera resolution prior to taking the picture from within the camera view. now for that, i need to perform heavy tweakings on the plugin. i am not a very good android native programmer but i am willing to learn, if i have to. links to any help materials will be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe my answer eliminates the need to tweak the native code.  Let me know...

Answer (score 0):

If resolution is all you need user to configure, here is a stab at a Cordova + Regular Camera plugin solution.  Obviously, you'll want to build something a little better looking than using the built-in Javascript prompts, but this gives you the idea.  Once this works, you can swap out the prompts for your own customized UI form to get the resolution parameters.

```
function takePictureWithUsersSelectedResolution()
{

    var userSelectedQuality = prompt("Please enter the picture quality"); 
    var userSelectedWidth = prompt("Please enter the picture width");
    var userSelectedHeight = prompt("Please enter the picture height");

    navigator.camera.getPicture
    (                           
        function onSuccess(imageData) 
        {                   
            // save the pic or do something else with it
            yourSaveFunction(imageData);
        }, 

        function onFail(message) 
        {
            // do something with the error
            yourErrorLoggingFunction(message);

        },

        { 
            // *** Main Settings You Need to Customize ***
            quality : userSelectedQuality,
            targetWidth: userSelectedWidth,
            targetHeight: userSelectedHeight            
        }
    ); 

}
```

See the Docs for more info about the settings you can send into the camera plugin:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: thanks for your response.
i tried this already. there is no change in picture resolution. the main reason that i want to change picture resolution is that my app requires transmission of data to server using mobile network. those data includes pictures taken by the app users. i need to decrease the size of image to save their data costs by minimizing the camera resolution.
your code doesn't bring about any significant change in file size.

Comment: @JadeSync The Quality parameter changes the amount of Jpg or Png compression so depending on the picture it may not make a lot of difference.  Where you could get more savings would be to try scaling the Height and Width.  Reduce those by half for example but keep the Quality high, then rescale to original size once uploaded to server.  This is roughly equivalent to reducing resolution by half.  Make sense?  Again, this was a stab at it to keep you from going native, which I don't recommend if you can help it.

Comment: thanks again.
i tried that a while ago. change in file size is insignificant. reduces an image of 2.3 MB to 2.1 MB. i need to drop the file size to 1 MB tops.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work, it was worth a shot.  Curious though, you are saying you cut the width/height by 50% but it only reduced the file size by ~10%?  Seems like a strange result.